# load data in sql table if table exists but it is empty

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, mariadb, pymysql

I am writing a python script which connects to the SQL database. It creates databases based on the folder paths and tables based on the files present in those folders in corresponding databases.

My following code is doing everything fine but I want to optimize it in a way that it loads the data into tables only if the tables are empty.

The problem with the following code is that whenever I run it, it checks if the table is not present, it creates the table and if the table is already there, it moves on but when it comes to loading data into tables, every time run the script, it loads the data into tables from file 1.

I want to tweak it in a way that it loads data into tables only and only if the data is already not present in it. If the data is present, the code move on.

I tried to do something like **create table if not exists** but not successful.

```
hostname = 'hostname'
username = 'usrname'
password = '12345'
database = 'd1'
portname = '12345'
from mysql.connector.constants import ClientFlag
import pathlib
import sys
import os
import mysql.connector
import subprocess
from subprocess import *
import time
from termcolor import colored


print(colored('\nConnecting SQL database using host = '+hostname+' , username = '+username+' , port = ' +portname+ ' , database = ' +database+'.','cyan',attrs=['reverse','blink']))
print('\n')
myConnection = mysql.connector.connect(user=username, passwd=password,host=hostname,port=portname,database=database,client_flags=[ClientFlag.LOCAL_FILES])
myCursor =myConnection.cursor()

rootDir35 = '/mnt/Wdrive/pc35/SK/E13'
filenames35 = os.listdir(rootDir35)
root35 = pathlib.Path(rootDir35)
non_empty_dirs35 = {str(p35.parent) for p35 in root35.rglob('*') if p35.is_file()}
#35
try:
        print(colored('**** Starting Performing SQL-Queries for pc35 **** \n','green',attrs=['reverse','blink'] ))
        for f35 in non_empty_dirs35:
                dB35 = f35.replace('/','_') or f35.replace('-','_')
                for dirName35, subdirList35, fileList35 in os.walk(rootDir35):
                        if dirName35 == f35:
                                p1135= 'Current Working Directory is:   %s' %f35+ ' '
                                print(colored(p1135,'cyan'))
                                createDB35='CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS %s' %dB35
                                myCursor.execute(createDB35)
                                p135='Database of pc35 Created :        %s' %dB35
                                print(colored(p135,'cyan'))
                                useDB35='use %s' %dB35
                                myCursor.execute(useDB35)
                                myConnection.commit()
                                p235= 'Database in use :               %s' %dB35
                                print(colored(p235,'cyan'))
                                print(' ')
                                for fname35 in fileList35:
                                        completePath35 ='%s' %dirName35+'/%s'%fname35
                                        tblname35 = os.path.basename(fname35).split('.')[0]
                                        if '-' not in tblname35:
                                                if '.' not in tblname35:
                                                       sql35= 'CREATE TABLE if not exists %s (Datum varchar(50), Uhrzeit varchar(13), UpsACT_V varchar(6), UpsPRE_V varchar(6), IpsACT_A varchar(6), IpsPRE_A varchar(6), PpsACT_W varchar(6), PpsPRE_W varchar(10), UelACT_V varchar(6), UelPRE_V varchar(6), IelACT_A varchar(8), IelPRE_A varchar(8), PelACT_W varchar(8), PelPRE_W varchar(8), Qlad_Ah varchar(10), Qlast_Ah varchar(10))' %(tblname35)
                                                        myCursor.execute(sql35)
                                                        myConnection.commit()
                                                        test35 = 'The Table                %s              '              %tblname35+               'in database             %s             '%dB35+'is created'
                                                        print(colored(test35,'yellow'))
                                                        loadData35= "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  '%s' "  %completePath35 + "INTO TABLE %s" %tblname35
                                                        myCursor.execute(loadData35)
                                                        myConnection.commit()
                                                        p335='Data loaded from file      %s              ' %fname35
                                                        p435='               into table %s              ' %tblname35
                                                        p535 = p335 + p435
                                                        print(colored(p535,'green'))
                                                        print(' ')
        print(colored('**** SQL-Queries for pc35 successfully executed **** \n','green',attrs=['reverse','blink']))
except:
        print(' ')
        print(colored('**** SQL queries for pc35 doesnot executed. Please refer to the report or user manual for more details ****','red',attrs=['reverse','blink']))
        print(' ')
```

What I want is something like **load data if not exists in table**.
what do you think, is it possible or what should I do to achieve this?

Comment: Also needed:  `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %s` and test for result > 0.

Comment: It would be better to experiment from the mysql commandline tool until you get the desired SQL statements, _then_ build the python baggage around them.  As it is, I can't tell whether the SQL is wrong or the python is wrong.

Comment: What I am doing now is `check135 = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %s' %tblname35
myCursor.execute(check135)
 result35 = myCursor.fetchone()         number_of_rows=result35[0]`

if the number_of_rows variable contatins any non zero value, it means that table aready contains some data. Therefore using if else statement in python, we can easily load data based on condition described above. I hope this might help someone else out there.